# ¿Como usar attach pasando un array adicional?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy un poco perdido, asi que espero y puedan entender mi problema.

Así aplico la relaciona de mi tabla usando los datos almacenados en `services`:

```
$event =  Event::create($request->all());
$event->services()->attach($request->get('services'));
```

Este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo bien hasta ahí, pero tengo una columna extra llamada "time", de igual forma quiero pasar una 2da variable al método anterior, pero realmente no se como aplicarlo.

Las variables son 2 array. El primero vendría siendo datos para `service_id` y el segundo para `time` en la tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente pasar la variable adicional pero aun sin éxito: *`"message": "Array to string conversion"`*. ¿Cómo realmente debo aplicarlo?

```
 $event->services()->attach($request->get('services'),  ['time'=>$request->get('times')]);

 $event->services()->attach(['service_id'=> $request->get('services')],  ['time'=>$request->get('times')]);
```

Comment: Entonces ¿cuáles valores son los que quieres pasar? ¿33 y 0 o 2 y 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenemos que `services` son 2 y 3, mientras que `times` son 33 y 0.

```
$services = [2, 3];
$times = [33, 0];
```

Desde ya te funciona añadir N relaciones a la tabla pivote mediante un array de IDs

```
 $event->services()->attach($services);
```

Y según el ejemplo [que hay en la documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#attaching-detaching), tu técnica funcionaría cuando hay una sola relación (y la data del pivote va como array en el segundo parámetro), por lo que podrías probar un bucle:

```
 foreach($services as $index => $service_id) {
    $time = $times[$index];
    $event->services()->attach($service_id, ['time'=>$time]);
 }
```

pero eso es bastante frágil porque siendo data cuyo origen no controlas, te puede llegar cualquier cosa. Esto se mitiga un poco manejando el caso de los índices que falten (los dejo por defecto en cero)

```
 foreach($services as $index => $service_id) {
    $time = $times[$index] ?? 0;
    $event->services()->attach($service_id, ['time'=>$time]);
 }
```

En el mismo ejemplo de la documentación, muestran que la inserción de un array de relaciones, cada uno con data extra para el pivote, tiene la sintaxis:

```
$user->roles()->attach([
    1 => ['expires' => $expires],
    2 => ['expires' => $expires],
]);
```

En tu caso, sería

```
$event->services()->attach([
    2 => ['time' => 33],
    3 => ['time' => 0],
]);
```

¿Cómo se llega a eso? Debe haber formas más elegantes, pero yo lo haría mezclando colecciones:

```
$payload = collect($services)
            ->combine(collect($times) 
            ->map(fn($time)=> ['time'=>$time]))
            ->toArray();

 
$event->services()->attach($payload);
```

(sigue siendo igual de frágil, necesitas hacer buen uso del validator)

Comment: No lo comprendia de todo con esos ejemplos de la documentación pero con esto me quedo mas que claro, muchas gracias!